# ADB and Galaxy A71 5G

Tags: adb, airplane-mode

I use ADB to reprogram the toggle for Airplane Mode such that turning on Airplane Mode does not turn off WiFi and Bluetooth. The command is:
adb settings put global airplane_mode_radios cell,nfc,wimax

I've used this on several different phones, including my Galaxy S20 with no issues. On my wife's A71 5G, it accepts the command, but only partially works. Following the command, if I turn on Airplane Mode, WiFi stays on (good), but Bluetooth turns off (bad). Turning Airplane mode off brings back Bluetooth and continues to leave WiFi on.

BTW, do phones still come with a Wimax radio?

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch(not only on or off) the mobile data and wifi using adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228469/how-to-switchnot-only-on-or-off-the-mobile-data-and-wifi-using-adb)